# How to get path for jQuery in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

What's the code to programmatically get the path to jQuery in Moodle (Version 3.4)? On my recent moodle it's '/theme/jquery.php/core/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' but I need to get it dynamically in case of updates etc.

Comment: For what case do you need the jquery path?

Comment: We have a special workflow where we build static local webpages that are embedded in moodle via iframe. For these static pages I want to use the same jquery as moodle does …

Comment: a local moodle plugin page or an external ressource ?

Comment: don't well understood you question. what do you mean by 'local moodle plugin page'?

Comment: If you create a own local plugin you can define there pages, that what i mean.

Comment: no, we're not creating a plugin, just place html/php documents insinde the moodle doc-root and put these URLs inside an inframe in moodle questions.

Comment: Well that is not a good style, pleas create a local plugin for that purpose and add there your styles or patch a theme to fit your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method where the URL of each jquery plugin (and the jquery library itself) is programatically build is `jquery_plugin` at `lib/outputrequirementslib.php` (with params `jquery` and `core`).

Ultimately that method builds it approximately like so:

```
$CFG->wwwroot . '/theme/jquery.php/core/' . $file
```

where $file value is taken from required file `lib/jquery/plugins.php`, where the current jquery version-file is declared.